Pea stone or not, around shower drain at dry pack on top of PVC pan liner
I'm building a traditional shower pan. Poured concrete pre slope, next will be the PVC sheet pan liner. I'm planning on using a dry pack bed for under the tile. Should I use pea stone around the drain so the weep holes don't get blocked or just dry pack tight around the drain because any water would weep through the dry pack anyway?

No pea stone is needed. The pvc liner is bolted to a drain assembly. The assembly has its' own weep drains. The drain itself is screwed into the assembly and can be adjusted for height of the drypack.
